# Mediaplayer, exoplayer and audio streaming

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am working on an Android app that streams audio. I am currently using Android MediaPlayer. If I seek to a certain position in the audio file while streaming and at the same time seek to the same position in the same audio file that has been downloaded to my mac (using QuickTime Player), I don't come to the same audio position. The display says that I am at the same position (02:49:54) but the audio is not playing the same sound (the streaming server is 20-40 seconds behind the correct position). I tried the Exoplayer Demo app and replaced one of the static urls with my own streaming url. The same thing happens with Exoplayer. My friend that works as an iOS developer has no problem seeking to the right position while streaming (using the same streaming server). I also have the issue that sometimes the streaming stops seconds before the actual audio streaming is done. I hoped that Exoplayer would solve my issues, since the old MediaPlayer seems to be a bit buggy. Does anyone have any idea on why I am having these issues?

Comment: I have now tested Vitamio https://www.vitamio.org/en/  . Vitamio do not have this error, it seeks to the correct position. But I am not able to make Vitamio work with my current implementation at this moment.

Comment: Which file is? Can you share the url?

Comment: @KasperFinneNielsen I am having similar problems, for me the Android stream works BUT the seek DOES NOT. I get the `Stream has no duration and is therefore not seekable` message. At the same time, WORKS perfectly on my friend's iOS version. Did you find any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by added -t to the LAME command that I use to reduce the size of the mp3s. If you add -t option then no extra LAME info is written to the audio file:

Kaspers-MacBook-Pro:Bomben finne$ mediainfo bomben2.mp3
General

Complete name : bomben2.mp3

Format : MPEG Audio

File size : 67.9 MiB

Duration : 3h 17mn

Overall bit rate mode : Constant

Overall bit rate : 48.0 Kbps

Audio

Format : MPEG Audio

Format version : Version 1

Format profile : Layer 3

Duration : 3h 17mn

Bit rate mode : Constant

Bit rate : 48.0 Kbps

Channel(s) : 1 channel

Sampling rate : 32.0 KHz

Compression mode : Lossy

Stream size : 67.9 MiB (100%)

But still this should be fixed, since it works fine on iOS. Now you can reproduce the error by running:

lame -m m --preset cbr 48 source.mp3 output.mp3

and then to make it work:

lame -t -m m --preset cbr 48 source.mp3 output.mp3

I have created this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158627&thanks=158627&ts=1425655288

Comment: hey @Kasper when streaming audio with no album art how to hide the black screen of the playerview?

Comment: right now I have just set the height to a small number and used a matching backgound with my controls